# Adding values to multibar plot using matplotlib bar

Tags: pandas, python-3.8

I am using the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Women = [115, 215, 250, 200]
Men = [114, 230, 510, 370]

n=4
r = np.arange(n)
width = 0.25


plt.bar(r, Women, color = 'b',
        width = width, edgecolor = 'black',
        label='Women')
plt.bar(r + width, Men, color = 'g',
        width = width, edgecolor = 'black',
        label='Men')

plt.xlabel("Year")
plt.ylabel("Number of people voted")
plt.title("Number of people voted in each year")

# plt.grid(linestyle='--')
plt.xticks(r + width/2,['2018','2019','2020','2021'])
plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

It generates the plot I need but I am not able to add the values to the bar plot on the top. i.e. I want the values for both `Women` and `Men` displayed for each bar on the top or center of the bar. I must use the function `plt.bar` as the code is grandfathered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop over your data lists and place `plt.text` above each bar.

Add this between `plt.legend()` and `plt.show()`:

```
for i, w, m in zip(r, Women, Men):
    plt.text(i, w + 10, str(w), color='b', 
             horizontalalignment='center')

    plt.text(i + width, m + 10, str(m), color='g', 
             horizontalalignment='center')

# Manually increase the top y-axis limit to make room for the
# label of the tallest bar
plt.ylim(0, 550);
```

[image: Plot of result]